# Database name Regex restriction

Tags: java, regex, database

I've to create a java regex that disable creation of databases.
(I'm following these restrictions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html)

Can anyone help me to build a regex with this restriction [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] ?

This is my snippet:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9a-zA-Z$_]");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("userdatabase");
    System.out.println(matcher.matches());
```

Comment: The database name can contains [0-9a-zA-Z] and $ and _ character. I don't know how create a pattern for regex.

Comment: What do you have as a regular expression?  And why isn't it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify a quantifier.  Your expression will only match one character.

Try changing it to:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9a-zA-Z$_]+");
```

The `+` indicates that it should be that expressions 1 or more times.

Comment: Thanks you, but I've to return false also when string have blank spaces ("The user") for example. Can I add this rule to pattern?

Comment: A space won't match against `[0-9a-zA-Z$_]`, so it won't accept "The user"

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks. I'm very newbie with regex!!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean regex for 0-9a-zA-Z$_ it is simple:

```
    String string = "the input";
    String regularExpression = "^[0-9a-zA-Z$_]+$";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regularExpression);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    System.out.println(matcher.matches());
```

If you mean that you don't want to execute "CREATE TABLE" commands then you can check something like this:

```
    String regularExpression = ".*create\stable.*";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regularExpression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Answer (score 0):

i read out of the context you want to avoid SQL injection?
if yes, you could simply use [prepared statements](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead of sql strings.